# How can I use form_validation in CI3?

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, validation

I'm coding a project with CI and I have a doubt about the form_validation code, my professor tough me one way to put the rules in the form_validation with arrays, like this

```
$config = array (
  'jugador' =>array(
    array(
    'field' => 'correoJug',
    'label' => 'Correo',
    'rules' => 'trim|required|htmlspecialchars',
    ),
    array(
    'field' => 'nombreJug',
    'label' => 'Nombre',
    'rules' => 'trim|required|htmlspecialchars',
    ),
    array(
    'field' => 'tagJug',
    'label' => 'Tag',
    'rules' => 'trim|required|htmlspecialchars', 
    ),
    array(
    'field' => 'apellidosPatJug',
    'label' => 'Apellido paterno',
    'rules' => 'trim|required|htmlspecialchars',
    ),
    array(
    'field' => 'apellidosMatJug',
    'label' => 'Apellido materno',
    'rules' => 'trim|required|htmlspecialchars',
    ),
    array(
    'field' => 'password',
    'label' => 'Password',
    'rules' => 'trim|required|htmlspecialchars',
    )
  )
);
```

Where 'jugador' is used for one view, my doubt is the next, I want to use the form_validation for another view, do I need to add another arrays at the end for my another view, like this:

```
    array(
    'field' => 'apellidosMatJug',
    'label' => 'Apellido materno',
    'rules' => 'trim|required|htmlspecialchars',
    ),
    array(
    'field' => 'password',
    'label' => 'Password',
    'rules' => 'trim|required|htmlspecialchars',
    )
)
    'OG' =>array(
    array(
    'field' => 'correoOg',
    'label' => 'Correo',
    'rules' => 'trim|required|htmlspecialchars',
    ),
    array(
    'field' => 'password',
    'label' => 'Password',
    'rules' => 'trim|required|htmlspecialchars',
    )
 );
```

Or do I need to create another variable in the same file OR I just need to create another form_validation file.

I hope you understand what I'm saying and could help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create multiple validation array in single file.

```
$config = array(
  'first_validation' => array(
    'name' => 'trim|required',
    'password' => 'trim|required'
  ),
  'second_validation' => array(
    'phone' => 'trim|required',
    'email' => 'trim|required'
  )
)
```

and in **CONTROLLER**

```
if ($this->form_validation->run('first_validation') == TRUE) {
   //success
} else {
  // error
}
```

in some another controller

```
if ($this->form_validation->run('second_validation') == TRUE) {
   //success
} else {
  //error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to created another variable to set form validation like this

```
$config['form1'] = array(
               array(
                     'field'   => 'username', 
                     'label'   => 'Username', 
                     'rules'   => 'required'
                  ),
               array(
                     'field'   => 'password', 
                     'label'   => 'Password', 
                     'rules'   => 'required'
                  ),
            );

$config['form2'] = array(
               array(
                     'field'   => 'email', 
                     'label'   => 'Email', 
                     'rules'   => 'required'
                  ),
            );
```

Than use as you are doing .